# Timeout is displaying Text in command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I know I posted a comment recently, but I need more help, (this is probably some thing really obvious).
Anyway, my problem is when I use

```
timeout 2
```

It shows the text, that I do not want the user to see.

```
Waiting for NUMBER seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

How do I make it so this text can not be seen?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please do not edit my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timeout /t 2 >nul
```

Not sure just `timeout 2` would work - and make sure there's a space after the `2`

...Ah, yes the /T is optional...make an uncommon amount of sense.